# How to filter table to date when it has a timestamp with time zone format?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very large dataset - records in the hundreds of millions/billions.

I would like to filter the data in this column - i am only showing 2 records of millions:

```
arrival_time 
2019-04-22 07:36:09.870+00
2019-06-07 09:46:09.870+00
```

How can i filter the data in this column to only the date part? as in I would like to filter where the arrival_time is 2019-04-22 as this would give me the first record and any other records which have the matching date of 2019-04-22?

I have tried to cast the column to timestamp::date = "2019-04-22" but this has been costly and does not work well given i have such vast amounts of records.

sample code is:

```
select 
*
from 
mytable
where 
arrival_time::timestamp::date = '2019-09-30'
```

again very costly if i cast to date format as this will be done before the filtering!

any ideas? I am using postgresql and pgadmin4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
where (arrival_time::timestamp)::date = '2019-09-30'
```

Is converting `arrival_time` to another type.  That generally precludes the use of index and makes it harder for the optimizer to choose the best execution path.

Instead, compare to same data type:

```
where arrival_time >= '2019-09-30'::timestamp and
      arrival_time >= ('2019-09-30'::timestamp + interval '1 day')
```

Comment: thanks - great answer - the conversion to date was too costly!

Comment: @DataScience . . . Actually the conversion itself is probably pretty fast.  The performance issue is the affect on the optimizer, particularly that it precludes the use of indexes and partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter for the upper and lower bounds of that day.

```
...
WHERE arrival_time >= '2019-04-22'::timestamp
      AND arrival_time < '2019-04-23'::timestamp
...
```

Like that an index on `arrival_time` should be usable and help to improve performance.

Comment: This did not work and returned 0 records - I assume because it has a timestamp with timezone this is causing a problem?